# FortiClient SSL VPN: Failed to start SSLVPN tunnel client

Tags: windows, vpn, ssl-vpn

I have been using FortiClient on Windows 10 for years, using Internet Explorer 11 to connect to the VPN gate-way. Suddenly it has stopped working. After entering pin + 6 digit keyfob value, the usual status screen loads, but an error window pops up with the title

> VBScript: SSLVPN tunnel client

and the text

> Failed to start SSLVPN tunnel client. Please check if it is installed
>   properly. You need administrator privileges on your PC to install or
>   update the tunnel client

Pressing OK on this window, I get the usual status status screen, but with Connect and Disconnect buttons grey shaded and the status text line

> SSL VPN Client not installed

How can I get FortiClient working again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the local FortiClient using "Add or remove programs", and reinstall new client from [FortiClient home page](http://www.forticlient.com/)

Answer (score 0):

See if the FortiClient SSLVPN Service is actually running.

Being the huge nerd that I am I regularly go through my services to prevent some services from starting automatically. Then I forget about it. (obviously, reinstalling the client would fix this as well. )